# Net::SSLeay failing Applink tests with openssl

Tags: perl, compilation, openssl

I'm trying to compile Perl, OpenSSL, and NET::SSLeay from scratch. This is on Windows, using Visual Studio 2017 (not cygwin or mingw), Windows 10, compiling 32 bit Perl (v5.30.1), OpenSSL (1.1.1d), Net::SSLeay (1.88).

The compilation succeeds but one test for NET::SSLeay fails:

> t\local\39_pkcs12.t .................... OPENSSL_Uplink(6CF30350,08):
>   no OPENSSL_Applink t\local\39_pkcs12.t .................... Dubious,
>   test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100) Failed 19/19 subtests

All other tests pass (external tests are disabled). OpenSSL's self tests pass. This appears to be a known issue with Net::SSLeay and has a mention in README.Win32, but with pre-compiled binaries. The recommended fix is to compile OpenSSL yourself, which is what I'm already doing.

It looks like the applink is controlled by the compiler directive -D"OPENSSL_USE_APPLINK", which is already being supplied. This is from the basic Configure, and not something I added. The define is being supplied to every call of cl and it is being used during compilation. However, when I check for it through Net::SSLeay, it's missing:

> perl -M"Net::SSLeay" -e "print Net::SSLeay::SSLeay_version(1);"
>   compiler: cl /Zi /Fdossl_static.pdb /Gs0 /GF /Gy /MD /W3 /wd4090 /nologo /O2 /WX -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_PART_WORDS -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DRMD160_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM

Most of those are what is used but -DOPENSSL_USE_APPLINK is notably missing. I do see it mentioned in the documentation for Net::SSLeay for SSLeay_version: "SSLEAY_CFLAGS   - e.g. 'compiler: gcc -D_WINDLL -DOPENSSL_USE_APPLINK .....'". So it looks like that define should be present and is somehow getting lost either after the compilation or during Net::SSLeay's compilation.

Is there a way to resolve this issue and make the Net::SSLeay tests pass?

Comment: It might well be that the failed test is not critical for the usage of the module. So you could try skip the tests and see if the module still works first?

Comment: You could also try report the issue on [the issue tracker](https://github.com/radiator-software/p5-net-ssleay/issues)

Comment: Skipping the test does allow the perl module to be installed. I'm not quite at the point where I can fully test it, as there's other Perl modules failing. My concern is that if I ignore this failure I'll end up with a hard-to-diagnose intermittent error much later on.